# Symfony 5 LiipImagineBundle images not created into the cache

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

With Symfony 5, I try to use LiipImagineBundle which correctly worked with Symfony 4.4. Now, images aren't created into the cache designated by the configuration.

So the images are no longer displayed and I get these kind of errors:

> GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/resolve/thumb/images/no-photo.jpg
> 404 (Not Found)

This is my LiipImagine configuration:

```
liip_imagine:
  resolvers:
    default:
      web_path:
        web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
        cache_prefix: "images/cache"
  filter_sets:
    thumb:
     quality: 75
     filters:
       thumbnail:
         size: [360, 360]
         mode: outbound
         allow_upscale: true
    medium:
     quality: 75
     filters:
       thumbnail:
         size: [500, 500]
         mode: outbound
         allow_upscale: true
    tiny:
     quality: 75
     filters:
       thumbnail:
         size: [35, 35]
         mode: outbound
```

Comment: Try adding a slash in front: cache_prefix: "/images/cache" . Or else, what if you just use the default settings: web_path: ~ ? What is your version of the liip_imagine? Maybe upgrading it would help since other people also had that problem https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/897

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. With web_path: ~ or cache_prefix: "/images/cache", it doesn't work. My LiipImagineBundle version is 2.3.0

Comment: Maybe since the default data-root setting for Symfony 5 is /web and you have /public. So try to also set your data-root to public...
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: '%kernel.project_dir%/public'

Comment: Many thanks also for your help. However, I added this setting and it unfortunately doesn't change the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on nginx php-fpm and after one day of digging i found out that nginx it's not trying to go any further after the image it's generated because get's an 404 so you need to add in your nginx conf something like:

```
# assets, media
location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
    expires    7d;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

and so like that if the image it's not found it will hit index with the query string.

Comment: this didn't help, switching back to apache helped though.